# What's the difference between spherical symmetry and rotational symmetry in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, commutator, rotation

I am reading quantum mechanics and these two concepts are confusing me.

1. Griffths' QM book says "perturbation $H'\sim p^4$ is considered "spheric symmetric", so it commutes with $L^2$ and $L_z$." From my intuition, I understand potential $V(\mathbf r)=V(r)$ is spheric symmetric. However, why is operator "$p^4$" still spheric symmetric? It is abstract to me.
2. Rotational symmetry in QM is $[H,R_\mathbf{n}(\phi)]=0$. I think spherical and rotational symmetry should be different, but I don't know the difference exactly.

Comment: Important to note: if a function is spherically symmetric, i.e. $\psi(\mathbf r)=\psi(r)$, then  the Fourier transform is spherically symmetric as well: i.e. $\hat\psi(\mathbf p)=\hat\psi(p)$. Here is a nice proof https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1311236/339958

Comment: Rotational symmetry may be about spaces such as the isospin space, which is not the physical space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spherical symmetry implies that the Hamiltonian $H$ commutes with the three angular momentum operators
$$
[H, L_x] = [H, L_y] = [H, L_z] = 0
$$
You can check that $p^4$ satisfies this condition, so is spherically symmetric. You can think of $p^2=\vec{p} \cdot \vec{p}$ as being a dot product of $\vec{p}$ with itself, and since dot products are invariant under rotations, so is $p^2$. Meanwhile, $p^4=(p^2)^2$ is simply a function of the scalar $p^2$, so is also rotationally invariant (meaning that a Hamiltonian built out of $p^4$ will be spherically symmetric).

"Rotational symmetry" strikes me as a vague phrase. Depending on context, it could refer to spherical symmetry, or it could refer to something weaker like cylindrical symmetry, which implies the Hamiltonian commutes with one of the angular momentum operators, for example
$$
[H, L_z] = 0
$$